# New to IOS/Swift/Realm. Getting this error: "Library not found for -lrealmcore-ios"

Tags: xcode

Trying to use a Realm database.

Following this YouTube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PmsJW59rNY8

When I try to build the project (command-B), I receive the error "Library not found for -lrealmcore-ios". Feel like I loaded the database correctly, but I'm still getting the error.

Installed CocoaPods and Realm without issues. Issued  'pod init' and 'pod install' commands. Edited Podfile to add "pod 'RealmSwift'"

Answer (score 0):

If the file named `lrealmcore-ios` is missing under folder project/pod/realm/core/, this error will occur. Delete Realm from the pod file and reinstall it.